# How to check the Limited Access on wifi in swift, like if my device is connected to wifi but that wifi don't have internet connection

Tags: ios, swift

I wanted to check if the wifi has an internet connection or not. Most of the solutions/methods including the alamofire return true only if the device is connected to wifi only, don't check if wifi has an internet connection or not.

Comment: You can use reachability and specify an Internet host name as the test point

Answer (score 0):

Apple's [reachability sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) only allows to get info if an interface is available that *might allow* a connection. There are some endpoints hosted by Apple for verifying if internet access is available. For example [this one](https://www.apple.com/library/test/success.html). You can create your own wrapper on top of Apple's reachability or use existing one called [Connectivity](https://github.com/rwbutler/Connectivity). It provides you such options:

```
connectedViaWiFi,
connectedViaWWAN,
connectedViaWiFiWithoutInternet,
connectedViaWWANWithoutInternet
```

You are interesting on `connectedViaWiFiWithoutInternet` and `connectedViaWWANWithoutInternet`. This library allow to configure which end points to use, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do:

```
var reachabilityManager = NetworkReachabilityManager()

private
var networkIsReachable : Bool{
    return reachabilityManager?.isReachable ?? false
}

private
var isEthernetOrWifiReachable : Bool{
    return reachabilityManager?.isReachableOnEthernetOrWiFi ?? false
}
```

Since there is no ethernet on mobiles *isReachableOnEthernetOrWiFi* will check for wifi

Comment: sorry mate @H.jacob this doesn't work from checking internet connection in wifi, it will return true even if wifi don't have internet connection